# Deselecionar itens ao mover entre listboxes

Tags: javascript, select

Na minha aplicação tenho duas listboxes, uma com "jogadores disponiveis" e outra com "jogadores escalados", bem como dois botões para mover os itens entre as mesmas, <kbd>>></kbd> e <kbd><<</kbd>.

Meu problema é o seguinte. Assim que seleciono algum item em uma das listbox, e na sequencia clico em algum item da OUTRA listbox, o item que foi clicado primeiramente ainda continua selecionado.

Preciso de um jeito para fazer o seguinte. Exemplo: Primeiramente clico em um nome na listbox da esquerda e o botão <kbd>>></kbd> para mover o item para a listbox da direita se habilita. Mas aí eu percebo que não era isso que eu queria e clico em algum nome da listbox da DIREITA dessa vez. Como agora há um selecionado nela, o botão <kbd><<</kbd> se habilita. Porém, a primeira opção clicada na outra listbox ainda continua selecionada, e o botão <kbd>>></kbd> ainda fica habilitado. Preciso que ao clicar em outra listbox, todos os itens que por ventura tiverem sidos selecionados na listbox anterior, sejam deselecionados.

Abaixo segue uma imagem do problema, com os dois botões de mover habilitados ao mesmo tempo, devido aquele problema que descrevi acima.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

E abaixo, segue o código que habilita e desabilita os botões:

```
function habilitarBotoes(){
    var disponiveis = document.getElementById("jogadores_disponiveis");
    var escalados = document.getElementById("jogadores_escalados");
    var toRight = document.getElementById("toRight");
    var toLeft = document.getElementById("toLeft");
    var salvar = document.getElementById("salvar");
    var data = document.getElementById("data");
    if((getOpts(disponiveis).length > 0) && (getOpts(disponiveis).length + escalados.length <= 5)){
        toRight.disabled = "";
    } else { 
        toRight.disabled = "disabled"; 
    }

    if(getOpts(escalados).length > 0){
        toLeft.disabled = "";
    } else {
        toLeft.disabled = "disabled";
        }

    if((escalados.options.length == 5) && (CheckDate(data) == true) ){
        salvar.disabled = "";
    } else {
        salvar.disabled = "disabled";
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho que o Sergio postou alguma coisa parecida há pouco tempo, tem que [pesquisar nas respostas dele](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:129+[javascript]) (talvez tenha sido jQuery),  e não se estranhe se começar a ler uma depois de outra e falar "nossa, legal isso... nossa! nossa!!" ;) Oh, yes, +1 pela pergunta bem formulada.

Answer (score 1):

Limpe os selecionados de um select quando o evento onChange do outro for disparado (demo em: http://jsfiddle.net/xgohnnnu/2/):

```
escalados.onchange = function () {
    limpaSelecionados(disponiveis); 
};

disponiveis.onchange = function () {
    limpaSelecionados(escalados);
};

function limpaSelecionados(lista) {
    //define a opçao selecionada como -1. como o indice das opçoes do select começa em 0, nao seleciona nenhuma opçao
    lista.options.selectedIndex = -1;

    //CASO A ACIMA NAO FUNCIONE EM ALGUM BROWSER, TENTE A OPÇAO ABAIXO
    //for (var i = 0; i < lista.options.length; i++) {
      //  lista.options[i].selected = false;
    //}
}
```